# function called by onsubmit never reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onsubmit

Probably a daft oversight but I have an HTML form similar to this:

```
<form onsubmit="updateProfile();">
    <input type="submit" value="Update Account">

    ..
    ...

</form>
```

And:

```
function updateProfile() {

    // never gets here

};
```

I set a breakpoint in the `updateProfile()` function but when I click the `Update Account` button it never gets there.

Can anyone give me a likely explanation?

Comment: Please make a fiddle reproducing the problem

Comment: Can you create an example?

Comment: It's work, take a look at **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dsxb9tr/1/)**;

Comment: did you try to use <form onsubmit="return updateProfile();"> ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Comment: I have just added break point in given fiddle and it's perfectly working for me.

Comment: To all: if it works as a snippet and does not work for him/her, then may be the cause in something in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

then in javascript you can do this

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    updateProfile();
});
```

and don't forget to import jquery library :)

Answer (score 2):

A form without an action attribute is not a form, according to standards - and will actually cause a page reload in some browsers.

To avoid this behavior update from

```
<form onsubmit="updateProfile();">
```

to

```
<form onsubmit="updateProfile(); return false;">
```

Comment: Thanks - seems that's what I was missing (previous answer solved the problem too).

Answer (score 1):

It seems i cannot reproduce your issue, look here is it similar?

`codepen` http://codepen.io/icrosil/pen/bdXyPL

Comment: Yes - not sure why it didn't work but the other answer solved it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form onsubmit="updateProfile(event);">
<input type="submit" value="Update Account">

..
...

</form>

function updateProfile(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 alert("it gets here buddy");

};
```

Answer (score 1):

May be a click handler is active somewhere in the document, catches the click event, prevents the default action to occur (returning `false` or using `event.preventDefault()`), hence the `submit` event never triggers from the form.